# Routing based on query parameter in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

My web application will be triggered from an external system. It will call one request path of my app, but uses different query parameters for different kinds of requests.

One of the parameters is the "action" that defines what is to be done. The rest of the params depend on the "action".

So I can get request params like these:

```
action=sayHello&user=Joe
action=newUser&name=Joe&address=xxx
action=resetPassword
...
```

I would like to be able to encode it similarly in the routes file for play so it does the query param based routing and as much of the validation of other parameters as possible.

What I have instead is one routing for all of these possibilities with plenty of optional parameters. The action processing it starts with a big pattern match to do dispatch and parameter validation.

Googling and checking SO just popped up plenty of samples where the params are encoded in the request path somehow, so multiple paths are routed to the same action, but I would like the opposite: one path routed to different actions.

One of my colleagues said we could have one "dispatcher" action that would just redirect based on the "action" parameter. It would be a bit more structured then the current solution, but it would not eliminate the long list of optional parameters which should be selectively passed to the next action, so I hope one knows an even better solution :-)

BTW the external system that calls my app is developed by another company and I have no influence on this design, so it's not an option to change the way how my app is triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single dispatcher action is probably the way to go, and you don't need to specify all of your optional parameters in the route. If `action` is always there then that's the only one you really need.

```
GET  /someRoute      controller.dispatcher(action: String)
```

Then in your action method you can access `request.queryString` to get any of the other optional parameters.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: I am **NOT** experienced Scala developer, so maybe presented snippets can be optimized... What's important for you they are valid and working.*

**So...**

You don't need to declare every optional param in the `routes` file. It is great shortcut for type param's validation and best choice would be convince '*other company*' to use API prepared by you... Anyway if you haven't such possibility you can also handle ***their*** requests as required.

In general: *the dispatcher* approach seems to be right in this place, fortunately you don't need to declare all optional params in the `routes` and pass it between actions/methods as they can be fetched  directly from request. In PHP it can be compared to `$_GET['action']` and in Java version of Play 2 controller - `DynamicForm` class - `form().bindFromRequest.get("action")`.

**Let's say that you have a route:**

```
GET     /dispatcher      controllers.Application.dispatcher
```

In that case your dispatcher action (and additional methods) can look like:

```
def dispatcher = Action { implicit request =>
    request.queryString.get("action").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("invalid") match {
      case "sayHello" => sayHelloMethod
      case "newUser"  => newUserMethod
      case _          => BadRequest("Action not allowed!")
    }
}

// http://localhost:9000/dispatcher?action=sayHello&name=John
def sayHelloMethod(implicit request: RequestHeader) = {
  val name = request.queryString.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("")
  Ok("Hello " + name )
}

// http://localhost:9000/dispatcher?action=newUser&name=John+Doe&address=john@doe.com
def newUserMethod(implicit request: RequestHeader) = {
  val name = request.queryString.get("name").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("")
  val address = request.queryString.get("address").flatMap(_.headOption).getOrElse("")
  Ok("We are creating new user " + name + " with address " + address)
}
```

Of course you will need to validate incoming types and values 'manually', especially when actions will be operating on the DataBase, anyway biggest part of your problem you have resolved now.

Comment: Almost 2 years passed after your answer. Is there any better solution in the latest play framework?

Comment: @Ikrom, I think the better solution is like the accepted answer, but using an option params: GET  /someRoute      controller.dispatcher(action: Option[String])